# React-native-camera error when compiling android, react-native 0.60.5

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

Upgrade from react-native 0.59.8 to 0.60.5

Set missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'

Debug works fine, but
when compiling the release get the error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-camera:compileMlkitReleaseAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-camera:mlkitReleaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:12.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-camera
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:12.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-camera
```